# How to import ENOENT so I can return it?

Tags: c, errno

If an error occurs, I need to return `ENOENT` but I'm not sure which library this is from and surprisingly nothing came up on a Google search.

Comment: First hit on google with "ENOENT c": http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <errno.h>
```

See [`errno(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors that can occur anytime. You can use `#include <errno.h>` or you can copy [this](http://paste.debian.net/708151/) function to your code, it contain all the network errors that may occur anytime.
You can also use `strerror()` and `perror()` to get description of the error by it's error number.